# Is it possible to obtain the triple $(1,\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2)$ from the triple $(2,\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> An ordered triple of numbers is given. It is permitted to perform the following
> operation on the triple: to change two of them, say $a$ and $b$, to $(a+b)/\sqrt2$ and $(a-b)/\sqrt2$. Is it possible to obtain the triple $(1,\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2)$ from the triple $(2,\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$?

So if we are given a triple $(a,b,c)$, then according to the rules we can transform $$(a,b,c)\mapsto \left((a+b)/\sqrt2,(a-b)/\sqrt2,c\right)$$ however  I noticed that applying the same transformation to the resulted triple gives $$\left((a+b)/\sqrt2,(a-b)/\sqrt2,c\right) \mapsto (a,b,c)$$ so this would imply that since $$(2,\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2) \mapsto \left( (2+\sqrt2)/\sqrt2,(2-\sqrt2)/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2 \right) = (\sqrt2+1, \sqrt2-1,1/\sqrt2)$$ which isn't the triple in question it cannot be achieved.

Is this the correct invariant in this problem? That is applying the transformation twice gives the identity?

Comment: Not following.  You are pointing out that applying the same operation twice to the same pair in the same order is just the identity.  But...of course you might apply the operation to other choices.  What if you first apply it to $ab$, then to $ac$ then to $ba$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observation is correct: applying the transformation **twice** on any two of the coordinates while leaving the third coordinate fixed does indeed return to the original coordinates. (Such a transformation is called an *involution* by the way.)

As was noted by @lulu in the comments, you are not restricted to only applying the transformation on the first two coordinates, so your calculation is not enough to demonstrate that the target triple is impossible to obtain. In other words, if we introduce notation, say $T_{12}$ for the transformation that operates on the coordinates $1$ and $2$, and similarly for the other pair of coordinates, we would need to demonstrate that any such sequence of these transformations won't work, e.g. $T_{12}T_{13}T_{12}$ and infinitely many others don't accomplish what you want them to.

This is an infinite task to calculate explicitly, so it's impossible without some shortcuts! Fortunately, there's a very nice shortcut. It turns out that each of the transformations $T_{ij}$ is a reflection and preserves length (magnitude) of vectors. You need to verify this:
$$
|T_{ij}(a, b, c)| = |(a, b, c)|. 
$$
Or just check that the the *squared* lengths are equal to avoid extra radicals, i.e., verify that
$$
\biggl( \frac{a + b}{\sqrt{2}} \biggr)^{\!2} + 
\biggl( \frac{a - b}{\sqrt{2}} \biggr)^{\!2} + \;
c^2 
= a^2 + b^2 + c^2.
$$
Strictly speaking, this only checks the case where $(i, j) = (1, 2)$, but the other two cases are completely analogous.

Now, a direct calculation, which I also leave to you is to verify that
$$
\bigl| ( 1, \sqrt{2}, 1 + \sqrt{2} ) \bigr|^2
\neq 
\bigl| ( 2, \sqrt{2}, 1 / \sqrt{2} ) \bigr|^2
$$

Comment: Thank you! This was very informative. I was stuck on thinking that the operation is only applicable for the first two coordinates. @sammy-black

Comment: This is an example of a broad idea that has utility far beyond this problem. Whenever you suspect that something is impossible, it is useful to ask *if it were possible what would need to be true?* Often there's a quantity that is preserved under a transformation, an *invariant* of that transformation. If you can find an invariant quantity **and** show that the quantity is **not** preserved (it varies), then you have a proof by contradiction.

Comment: This is the bread-and-butter of, for example, knot theory where many questions come down to distinguishing knots (difficult to guarantee since a given knot can be represented in myriad different forms) by working out a knot invariant and showing that the suspects have different values for this invariant.